# Campaign Hierarchy Related List

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I have a custom visual force page that is overriding the standard layout for salesforce campaigns.
I´m adding all the related list for a campaign in visual force with these tags:

```
<apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" />
<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" />
<apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" /> 
<apex:relatedList list="Attachments" />
```

I´m not able to find the list name in order to show the Campaign Hierarchy section, i mean this one:
[image]

Do you know which is the list name in order to show the above section ?

```
<apex:relatedList list="??" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is

```
<apex:relatedList list="childCampaigns"/>
```

This will render the Campaign hierarchy related list exactly as requested.

This was determined using the Schema Describe library.

I span this up in a DE and tested it on a child and parent campaign for you.

[image: Campaign Hierarchy]

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon! Please could you tell me more about Schema Describe Library. I would like to know what is and how i can use it.

Comment: Sure, the Schema Describe stuff is very well documented, and a good start is here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm basically it allows you to interrogate your data structure/metadata programmatically to retrieve field/label/list names etc.etc. very useful for working out API names, and dynamically referencing sObject fields/types.